# displaying values in json data of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have the wordpress custom post type "books", as well as a taxonomy called "genres". I need to import this data to my mobile app.

so using /wp-json/wp/v2/books, the data for one of books looks like this:

[image]

How do I get the actual name of the genre (in this case "Adventure") to be displayed, instead of the id "57"? I know that the value 57 corresponds with "Adventure", and I also know that i could rewrite this value locally, but it would be much simpler for me to get the actual value I want to work with right from the start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Did you try`'$genre_name = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id = $genre_id");` or something like that..

Comment: Looking at the codex you can also find this: `// Get term by id (''term_id'') in Categories taxonomy.
get_term_by('id', 12, 'category')`

Answer (score 1):

after some more hours i found what i had to modify. in

/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php

... i had to change the following line

```
$data[ $base ] = $terms ? array_values( wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' ) ) : array();
```

to

```
$data[ $base ] = $terms ? array_values( wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'name' ) ) : array();
```

using /wp-json/wp/v2/book, this lists the taxonomy value names instead of the taxonomy value ids.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether your custom post type taxonomy is set to show in the REST API.

In the code that creates the custom post type/taxonomy you'll need to check if the array option `show_in_rest` is set to `true`. If not, you'll need to add it eg.

```
// hook into the init action and call create_book_taxonomies when it fires
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_taxonomies', 0 );

// create two taxonomies, genres and writers for the post type "book"
function create_book_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Genres', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        // more labels here...
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_in_rest'      => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'book' ), $args );
```

After you’ve added your custom taxonomy to the WP-API using `show_in_rest`, you can navigate to the taxonomies or terms endpoint to see it in action.

For example, you could go then to `mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/terms/genre` to see all of your genres.

If you have a genre called 'Adventure' with an ID of 57, to see information about only the Adventure genre, you would visit `mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/terms/genre/57`

If you just wanted the structural information about the taxonomy, you could visit `mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/genre`

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Yes I know - i could set up a further data import in my app to get the information. But what i want is for the information to actually appear in  /wp-json/wp/v2/books. This way, in my app, i can use just this one json data import to get to the book titles as well as the genre (and any other taxonomy values i might assign)...